# NameError (uninitialized constant Aws::VERSION):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am integrating paperclip with S3 bucket in `RAILS 5`. I  am referring https://coderwall.com/p/vv1iwg/set-up-ruby-on-rails-with-paperclip-5-and-s3-using-aws-sdk-v2. 
I have written the following in my development.rb:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_region: 'us-west-2',
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: 'mybucket',
      access_key_id: 'my id',
      secret_access_key: 'my secret key'
      }
    }
```

I am getting the below error while uploading image:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Aws::VERSION):
```

I am using version 3.0.1 of `gem aws-sdk`

Comment: @AjayBarot: credentials will be in string. I also tried to create a yml file for credentials & load it but no luck

Comment: Check the version of `aws-sdk`. If its *< 2.0* then that explains the error.

Comment: I am using latest version i.e. aws-sdk (3.0.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have downgraded the aws-sdk version to  `aws-sdk (2.10.42)` and it works.

Comment: Same here, it seems it's an `aws-sdk 3.x` bug.

Comment: `aws-sdk 3.x` removed this constant but `paperclip` in current version 5.1.0 relies on this constant that's why it crashes. `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.10.47'` gives you the latest 2.x version which works fine with paperclip.

Comment: This works with Paperclip 5.1 but Peter DeWeese's answer works too and is a nicer workaround, allowing you to use the current aws-sdk

Answer (score 7):

Instead of downgrading, you can introduce the variable that paperclip is missing in the current version. Adding this file works with aws-sdk 3.0.1 and paperclip 5.1.0, and will probably work until paperclip is updated to accommodate the aws changes.

```
# config/initializers/aws.rb
Aws::VERSION =  Gem.loaded_specs["aws-sdk"].version
```

Comment: This is a better solution than using the old version of aws-sdk, works great for me with Paperclip 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my config for `CarrierWave` with `minimagick`, I think something similar can be done for your case:

**config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|       
     config.fog_credentials = {     
         provider:              'AWS',      
         aws_access_key_id:     ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],       
         aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],       
         region:                ENV['S3_REGION']        
     }      
     config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']       
 end
```